# Creating `sqlite_sequence` table gets error

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sqlite, database-table

I want to make a new table but it says my query is wrong, and I have no idea what's wrong with the query because I exported the database from SQLite Database browser.
Here's the query,

```
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq);
```

and it says

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'seq)' at line 1

and if i can create that table i wanna insert into that table with this,

```
INSERT INTO sqlite_sequence VALUES('objek',55);
```

I hope it wont do another error.

Please tell me your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The only missing on your DDL is that it lacks datatypes on the columns,

```
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence
(
    name VARCHAR(20),
    seq INT
);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a7b3/1)

**UPDATE 1**

- [MySQL Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-types.html)

Answer (score 2):

The sqlite_sequence table gets generated automatically when you assign a data field of a table to autoincrement (e.g. _id integer primary key autoincrement)

It is impossible to create table called sqlite_sequence manually because "Table Name cannot begin with sqlite_ as the object name reserved for internal use: SQLITE_SEQUENCE"

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the data types for `name` and `seq`.

Try:

```
create table SQLITE_SEQUENCE ( name varchar(255), seq int );
```

Answer (score 0):

define `data type` for fields(columns)

```
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name varchar(200),seq int(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a normal create table command for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE demo (id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE DEFAULT 0,name text);
```

And yeah there's no problem with the `INSERT` command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define data type after each table field Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence (
                name VARCHAR(45),   
                seq INT
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, you cannot manually create `sqlite_sequence` table because `sqlite_sequence` table is reserved to create it with [AUTOINCREMENT](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) internally.

[The doc](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html#the_autoincrement_keyword) says below:

> SQLite keeps track of the largest ROWID using an internal table named "sqlite_sequence". The sqlite_sequence table is created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table that contains an AUTOINCREMENT column is created.

So, if you try to manually create `sqlite_sequence` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence (
  name TEXT
);
```

Then, you get the error below:

> Parse error: object name reserved for internal use: sqlite_sequence